# How to detect when selected changed - ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to input value in textField when selected changed without click **Done** button, but don't know what event to detect when selected changed.

```
    var title: String = "Numbers"
    var rows: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
    var selectedIndex: Int = 0    
    var sender = UITextField()

    func showActionPickerString(onDone: ((ActionSheetStringPicker?, Int, Any?)->())?, onCancel: (()->())?) {
        let acp = ActionSheetStringPicker(title: title, rows: rows, initialSelection: selectedIndex, doneBlock: { (picker, index, value) in
            onDone?(picker, index, value)
        }, cancel: { (picker) in
            onCancel?()
        }, origin: sender)
        
        let doneBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
        doneBtn.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        doneBtn.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
        doneBtn.tintColor = .posGreen
        let customDoneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: doneBtn)
        acp?.setDoneButton(customDoneBtn)
        
        let cancelBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
        cancelBtn.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        cancelBtn.tintColor = .customRed
        let customCancelBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cancelBtn)
        acp?.setCancelButton(customCancelBtn)
        
        acp?.show()
    }
```

---

```
    showActionPickerString { (picker, index, value) in
        textField.text = value as? String
    } onCancel: {
        return
    }
```

---

**Library link:** https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are asking question about third party libraries, you should add a link to them. I guess you are using [this ActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0).

Since the `ActionSheetStringPicker` and all the others do not hand out the delegate callback `func pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)`, you can do two things:

**Either**

1. Add a property `var originalDelegate:UIPickerViewDelegate?` to your class
2. After calling `show`, get the `pickerView` property from your `acp`, try cast it to `UIPickerView`. It should succeed; if not you have to give up :-(
3. If successfull, store the `delegate` of that picker view in your own `originalDelegate` property
4. Set your class as the delegate of the picker view
5. In your Class, implement the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol methods. In each method, call the `orignalDelgate` methods
6. In `pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)`, handle the selection of a value. Don't forget to call the same method on the `originalDelegate`.

**or** (not recommended)

1. Change the library's code to hand out the `pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)`

Comment: thanks for your answers. Step 2, get pickerView from acp always return nil.

Comment: I see. Checking the code, you need to first show the picker and then exchange the delegate (see my updated answer)